# Why will a video game from the google play store be asking me for root/super users permissions?

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, 4.2-jelly-bean, malware

So I don't know if this is a question for here or security.stackexchange.com but the thing is I installed a game that ask me for root access to my system it seems suspicious and strange why will a game be asking for root access I assume to myself that it is some type of malware and I uninstalled the game yeah a game asking for root access what a malware and is that normal? 
the game is snipper 3D assassin free games By fun games for free

Comment: This is far from normal. They are trying to get root users to soft brick their devices. Probably more ransomware.

Comment: I knew it should I make a report to Google?

Comment: That's all you can do. Write a bad review about it and remember to look closely on what your games want to do.

Comment: Okay write a bad review!

Comment: Care to share the name of the app?

Comment: It's some snipper 3D assassin free games.  By fun games for free yeah fun malware for free!

Comment: Contact the developer through the email ID they've provided on their Play Store page and ask them why their app needs such dangerous permission? More so, ask them why they've not mentioned anything about that in app's description? No need to jump to reviews unless you don't hear from them for some days.

Comment: Oddly, fun games for free is a top developer. Wouldn't this root thing get noticed earlier?

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't be... There is no viable reason I can think of for a game to request or need root permissions.

If this game is from an official channel like Play Store, Amazon App Store, or F-Droid, do not grant the permission and remove it immediately. This should also be reported to the appropriate app market and given a comment or review warning other users of the potential problems.

This is likely a way of hijacking your device, installing malware of somekind, or ransomware of some kind.

If you granted root permissions and run the app, I would immediately backup important data and factory reset the device, but keep in mind that root permissions can allow the app to read and write to the /system partition which survives a factory reset, so a reflashing of the factory firmware, or wiping of system and reflashing a custom ROM is highly recommended.

Comment: Thats what I did I denied root access and removed the application.

Comment: Good... Now I just have to wonder how many people they have gotten, and how long it will take to get this app removed.

Comment: Well here is the name of the game it is snipper 3D assassin free games By fun games for free.

Comment: It's probably just an anti-cheat mechanism. I still would avoid it like the plague and leave a bad review, but it doesn't necessarily mean it's trying to hijack your device.  Plenty of legitimate games like MLB PI, etc. use this controversial - but allowed - practice to prevent cheating.

Comment: @acejavelin : would you consider incorporating [this link](http://blog.checkpoint.com/2016/05/09/viking-horde-a-new-type-of-android-malware-on-google-play/) (as an example; optionally, quoting the content) to further your claim about the game being possibly a malware?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted and the game detects it, then it will ask for root access in an attempt to prevent you from cheating, blocking ads, etc. If you deny root access, the game will most likely exit or crash.

You have two choices if you really want to play the game:

1. Play on a non-rooted device.
2. Install [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) with [RootCloak module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.devadvance.rootcloak2) on your rooted device so that the game cannot detect that you're rooted.

Comment: I never saw a game asking for root access in my life and I don't trust it to get full access to my system it seems suspicious like some type of malware.

Comment: I don't blame you.  But I've seen it and there are forum and reddit posts about it, so it does happen and obviously some shady devs feel justified in doing it. Although I don't agree with it, I would still call it a viable reason.  The better approach is to just exit and refuse to run like is done with Android Pay and the like.

Comment: It would help if you support your claim using those XDA and reddit posts. The popular opinion seems to be about malware, although theirs is not backed by anything credible either!